# Pandas pivot table plot column name vs values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly

I am new to Pandas. I have a data frame as shown below and below is the code for obtaining my DataFrame.

```
# Creating DF for Functional Range in Mode1
df_thd_funct_mode1 = df_thd_funct[(df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 2.5) | (df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 2.7) | (df_thd_funct['Supply'] == 3.6)]
 df_thd_funct_mode1_copy = df_thd_funct_mode1
# df_thd_funct_mode1.head()
    
    
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT = pd.pivot_table(df_thd_funct_mode1 ,index = ['Temp', 'xvalues','Supply'],values = ['0.0189','0.0378','0.1194','0.2159','0.3768','0.5925','0.9318','1.0711','1.1890'])
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.rename(columns={'0.0189':'94','0.0378':'100','0.1194':'110','0.2159':'115','0.3768':'120','0.5925':'124','0.9318':'128','1.0711':'129','1.1890':'130'}, inplace=True)
# df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.iplot()
df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT
```

[image]

I need to plot a graph such that column names `['94','100','110','115','120','124','128','129','130']` will be in X axis and its corresponding value in Y axis.

I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: It is difficult to say much without some samples from your data, not in a screenshot as it is right now, but in text as part of the post. Perhaps however doing `df_thd_funct_mode1_PVT.T.plot()`, would help you. 
This code plots the _transpose_ of your matrix, with columns as rows...

Comment: What is the corresponding value in Y axis?

Comment: Y value is the vlaue corresponding to each column ['94','100','110','115','120','124','128','129','130'],ex for 94 you can see .0320,.0318 etc

Comment: Which plot type do you want to choose, I think it is line plot for each column, isn't it?